# Naming convention for methods that put vs those that don't

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

A GAE entity can have multiple methods, some of which will `put` the entity to the datastore and some that don't.  I have trouble remembering which methods `put` and which don't, so I have to go check the source.  I'm tempted to use a naming convention.

Below is a trivial entity with one method that `put`s and two that don't.  I used a "_PUT" suffix to indicate that method that `put`s.

Has anyone used a naming convention like this and did you find it useful?

```
class Number(ndb.model):

    n = ndb.IntegerProperty()

    def double(self):
        self.n = 2 * self.n

    def add_one(self):
        self.n = self.n + 1

    def modify_PUT(self):
        self.double()
        self.add_one()
        self.put()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you know this is very personal, but as in the most of cases I use this to do  CRUD operations from an API I like to use the same names to the methods that represent the same operations, something like this *for example*:

```
class SpecialObject(ndb.model):     
   ...          
   def post_special_object(self):
       ...    
   def put_special_object(self):
       ...
   @classmethod    
   def get_special_objects(cls, id=None):
       ...  
   def delete_special_object(self):
       ...       
   ...
   <any other methods>
   ...
```

But for other hand in another projects I haven' t put methods in the definition class of the model data, so, depends.

Comment: Yes, definitely a personal thing but nice to see what works for people.  By the way, I'm talking about datastore puts and not a REST API put.